# How to create an ATG store?

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

I have been studying ATG for about 4 months and now I am facing a problem: even going through the documentation I can't find any document that can clearly explain how I can create a new empty store.

I know that I need to have my database users and schemas, the application server scripts (I'm using weblogic) and the module in Eclipse. But I can't find anywhere how to create a new store, implement it from the beginning and see the result in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such document for ATG. You either need to start from the Commerce Reference Store and customise that (in versions prior to ATG 11 would would strongly suggest not to use the CRS as your basis for a new site) or you can look at what the CRS executes for the `runAssembler` command, remove the CRS specific modules from that and then create, and include your own modules for the Storefront and your source code.

Comment: Thank you, I have already take a look in the runAssembler and ATG's documentation isn't really clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no empty store you can install and run. You have to build one. Or you can install CRS, which is not empty, but it is relatively straightforward to install and can be customized.

The documentation to follow:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52191_02/CRS.11-1/ATGCRSInstall/ATGCRSInstall.pdf
- https://www.sparkred.com/blog/installing-oracle-commerce-11-1-with-commerce-reference-store/
  *